# log4j2.properties file is not taken into account while log4j.properties file is

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

I migrated our spring boot application from the web.xml configuration file to java based configuration. In this application we use log4j2 for logging however we also have log4j because of some surrounding system which uses it, so we can not remove it.

After finishing with all the migration the logs were not working. I figured out that I have to add the following code into my application.properties file

```
logging.level.project.base.package=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate=INFO
```

Adding all these made logs to appear, however only the property file log4j.properties is recognized and the logs which are using log4j2 have the default logging pattern.

If I remove the log4j.properties file the log4j2 still doesn't work, moreover I get the following warning message

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I also tried to specify the config file path in application.properties in bought of the following ways

```
logging.config=application.properties
logging.config=classpath:application.properties
```

Our pom.xml dependencies are the following

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

We are not running using an embedded tomcat, so we have a config class that extends SpringBootServletInitializer. We use the 2.0.1.RELEASE Spring Boot Version.

Bellow you can find my 2 log4j config files

log4j.properties

```
conversionPatternShort=OLDLOGGGGER %5p %d %-30C{1}:%4L [%X{username}] - %m%n

### APPENDER
log4j.appender.crt=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.crt.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.crt.layout.ConversionPattern=${conversionPatternShort}

### Define Levels per package
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,crt
log4j.logger.some.package1=DEBUG,crt
log4j.logger.some.package2=DEBUG,crt
```

log4j2.properties

```
status=ERROR
dest=err
name=LocalConfig

### PATTERN
property.conversionPatternShort=%5p %d %-30C{1}:%4L [%X{username}] - %m%n

### APPENDER
appenders=crt

appender.crt.type=Console
appender.crt.name=crt
appender.crt.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.crt.layout.pattern=${conversionPatternShort1}

## LOGGER
## defining some loggers, foreach logger I have defined 
##        (name, level, additivity, appenderRef.crt.ref)
logger.xxxxx.name=namex
logger.xxxxx.level=DEBUG
logger.xxxxx.additivity=false
logger.xxxxx.appenderRef.crt.ref=crt

logger.yyyyy.name=namey
logger.yyyyy.level=DEBUG
logger.yyyyy.additivity=false
logger.yyyyy.appenderRef.crt.ref=crt

logger.hibernateUtil.name=org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper
logger.hibernateUtil.level=ERROR
logger.hibernateUtil.additivity=false
logger.hibernateUtil.appenderRef.crt.ref=crt

rootLogger.level=WARN
rootLogger.appenderRef.crt.ref=crt
```

I really can not find what change made the log4j2 not work anymore. Could you please help?

Comment: I also face the same issue. Finally I changed my configuration to log4j2.xml file

Comment: How exactly, you changed bought your config files to xml or only the log4j2? Did it just worked afterwards out of the box?

Comment: Yes you can do but the configuration looks verbose in XML file.

Comment: I am trying to make it work since a while now and having a plan B in case I will not find another answer soon it is nice, thank you.

Comment: And just to be sure, you moved bought config files to xml and it also worked out of the box afterwards, right? (yes is the answer to bought of my previous questions?)

Comment: Yes.. it worked.